# How to iterate through an Iterator of Rows

Tags: java

I want to iterate over the few first  Rows of my iterator , i am trying like the following to iterate over all the file:

```
Dataset<Row> DF = spark.read().format("csv").load("longfile.csv");
Iterator<Row> iter = DF.toLocalIterator();


while (iter.hasNext()) { // i want a condition here to iterate only over the 20 first lines of my CSV
    Row item = iter.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

My question is how to limit the iteration to only 20 ?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a int count and break when the count is completed :

```
Dataset<Row> DF = spark.read().format("csv").load("longfile.csv");
Iterator<Row> iter = DF.toLocalIterator();

int count = 0;

while (iter.hasNext()) { // i want a condition here to iterate only over the 20 first lines of my CSV
    count++;
    Row item = iter.next();
    System.out.println(item);
    if(count > 20) break;
    
}
```

Comment: Alright, if no other solution is proposed i will accept your answer as a solution to my question. Thanks

Comment: If you want the condition to be set at the top of the while loop then you could use this answer but move the condition inside the while conditions like so: `while (iter.hasNext() && count > 20)`

Comment: It actually yielded an error using such mechanism inside a while loop!

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: It works now thanks, but is it the best way to do it ? i mean is it of good practice to break a while loop like you do ?

Comment: You can use this way or use the one proposed by @sorifiend

Comment: @marcnicole It is standard practice to do it like @MedElgarnaoui has shown, we are basically imitating a `for` loop with a cap of 20